# Django collectstatic não atualiza aquivos modificados no s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-aws

Estou utilizando **Django 1.10.6**, segui [este tutorial para configurar media e staticfiles no s3](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) e quando rodo **collectstatic**, os arquivos não são atualizados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei um arquivo de settings para rodar o **collectstatic** localmente para sincronizar com o s3. Neste arquivo eu setei:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Funcionou perfeitamente.

Estou utilizando S3 em São Paulo, teoricamente o timezone do S3 é igual ao meu local e deveria funcionar corretamente. Mas não funcionou. Creio que o timezone que mostra no console do S3 seja diferente do timezone real dos arquivos.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Voce mesmo respondeu sua pergunta (antes de eu ve-la, ehehe!), mas não posso deixar de adicionar minha resposta, até para, também, documentar. Depois de ter vários problemas com static files, em vários servidores (cada um de uma forma diferente), encontrei uma soluçlão, que, para mim, parece mágica.Chama-se Whitenoise, abaixo como se faz a magia:

1) Instale o Whitenoise:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

2) Edit seu settings.py e adicione o Whitenoise na lista  `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` acima de todos os outros, a partir de  SecurityMiddleware do Django:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
     ....
]
```

3) Para suporte a compreensao de arquivos e cache, adicione ao `settings.py`:

```
 STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Abaixo vai um resumo (de um caso real) do que é importante ter no arquivo `settings.py`, além do mencionado no item 2.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
....

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Whitenoise se denomina como "Radically simplified static file serving for Python web apps", ou seja, não é exclusivo para o Django, mas como Django é python, então... A documentação tem um [tópico dedicado ao django](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html), contemplando, inclusive, instruções para Amazon CloudFront.

[Site do projeto.](https://pypi.org/project/whitenoise/)